# Angularjs Datatable Responsive plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm using Angularjs Datatable Responsive plugin like this page https://l-lin.github.io/withResponsive

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('responsive', true)
                .withOption('bAutoWidth', false)
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                .withDOM('frtip');
```

It works fine with no problems,but the datatable has radio button column that should be true but when I use responsive plugin this button appears false I don't know why.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem please?

Comment: Have you added dataTables.responsive file for CSS and JS ? ...show as much code as you can...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44624292/2690160